# Find Rank of given Linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $Q \in  M_{3 \times 3}\mathbb(R)$ is a matrix of rank $2$.

Let $T : M_{3 \times 3}\mathbb(R) \to M_{3 \times 3}\mathbb(R)$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(P) = QP$. Then rank of T is:

I feel that rankT = rank Q = $2$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Any idea on how to solve it ?

Thank you.

Comment: You could find a basis for your domain and see how many linearly independent vectors(matrices) are mapped to.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $QP=0$ if and only if $\operatorname{range}P\subseteq \ker Q$, therefore $$\operatorname{rk}T=9-\dim\ker T=9-\dim\hom\left(\Bbb R^3,\ker Q\right)=9-3\times 1=6$$

Comment: Thank for the answer, I have one doubt : I want to know how you are calculating the dimension of Ker T, I know that, Ker $T = (X \in M_{3\times 3}(R)): T(X) = 0)$, 
                   but I do not understand why are you calculating $\dim\hom\left(\Bbb R^3,\ker Q\right)$  ,  (ie Dimension Of all Linear transformation from $R^3$ to KerQ).   Can you please explain this step in more detail ??                                                                                               Thank you.

Comment: Because $X\in \ker T$ if and only if $X$ is a linear map to $\ker Q$.

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to solve my doubt with your hint but  still not getting it.   If $X \in$ Ker T.then T(X) = 0, and hence X $\in$ ker Q, Now if we consider X to be  a linear map from  $R^3$ to Ker Q. then X will become  a  matrix of order $1 \times 3$.  But X $\in$  $M_{3 \times 3}(R)$ then how can X have such dimensions ???                                                                                                        
            I know this might  be a little troublesome for you but please can explain it more clearly ?

Comment: $X$ is in $\ker T$ if and only if multiplication by $X$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\ker Q$. "Only if", because if $QX=0$ then the range of $X$ is in $\ker Q$. "If", because if multiplication by $X$ has range in $\ker Q$, then $QX=0$.